# How to get not truncated text from IUITextField

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have created a custom column header renderer for my AdvancedDataGrid which has a text and a little button inside. Everything works just fine, until a moment when I have to return a headerText by the button click.

Since my custom renderer is an extention of AdvancedDataGridHeaderRenderer it has inherited property label which is IUITextField. So, when I call label.text from inside the custom renderer I get only truncated text, but I need the original one.

Any idea how to get not truncated text from IUITextField? Or maybe the original text is stored somewhere else and I am looking in a wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the header text from the [headerText](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/advancedDataGridClasses/AdvancedDataGridColumn.html#headerText) property of the corresponding `AdvancedDataGridColumn`

Comment: And how I can get a reference to the corresponding AdvancedDataGridColumn from inside my custom renderer?

Comment: @Minime [listData.owner](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/BaseListData.html#owner) will give you the `AdvancedDataGrid` - from there you can go wherever you want. listData also has a `columnIndex` property if you want.